# After call to an object from the client side I Got Error Code CS1061

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS1061  'LoginModel' does not contain a definition for 'Model'
>   and no accessible extension method 'Model' accepting a first argument
>   of type 'LoginModel' could be found (are you missing a using directive
>   or an assembly
>   reference?)   Lb_Clinics  C:\Users\dibem\source\repos\Clinics\Lb_Clinics\Pages\Login.cshtml   25  Active

that was the error while trying to bind my object property with the text fields (to get a good validation).

I make as usual the following steps :

1. Create object with its properties (example : account)
2. Create a model class inherits from DbContext
3. add DbContext To the service
4. make an interface that takes the names of the methods only
5. implement those methods in a repository class (example :repo_Account)
6. Create A Page Razor Than create the ordinary methods OnPost OnGet OnPut
7. make the form with a method (post , put )

Am I missing something ??  I have tried to understand this error , i have searched into microsoft , it says this happen when you call a method that does not exist [Error Code CS1061](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs1061)

Here is My Implementation : 
1_Entity :

```
public class Account
    {
        public int AccountID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MinLength(3)]
        [MaxLength(100)]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MinLength(3)]
        [MaxLength(100)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        public bool Verified { get; set; }


    }
```

2 _ DbContext :

```
   public class ClinicalDbContext:DbContext
    {
        public ClinicalDbContext(DbContextOptions options ):base(options)
        {
            Database.EnsureCreated();
        }
        public DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
    }
```

3- Configuration of the services

a-

```
 public Startup(IConfiguration configuration,IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().
                SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.development.json", optional: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            Configuration = builder.Build() ;
        }
```

b-

```
services.AddDbContext<ClinicalDbContext>(option => {
                option.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
            });
```

4- Interface that nominate the methods

```
     public interface IAccount
        {
            //AddNewAccount ChangePassword ChangeEmailAddress Verify_Login

            void AddNewAccount(Account account);
            void ChangePassword(int AccountID, string Password);
            void ChangeEmailAddress(int AccountID, string UserName);
            int Verify_login(string UserName, string Password);
        }
```

6 - calling Interface to bind it with the IAction events in cshtml.cs (Login.cshtml.cs)

```
  public class LoginModel : PageModel
    {

        private readonly IAccount _account;
        public LoginModel(IAccount account)
        {
            _account = account;
        }
        [BindProperty]
        public Account Account { get; set; }

        public IActionResult OnPostAsync(Account Account)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Page();
            }
            int ID = _account.Verify_login(Account.UserName, Account.Password);
            if (ID > 0)
            {
                return RedirectToPage("/Index");
            }
            return Page();
        }

5 - Repository that implement those methods
 public class Repo_Account :IAccount
    {
        #region Instance Of Account 
        private Account _Account;
        public Account Account { get { return new Account(); } set { _Account = value; } }
        #endregion

        #region private read only instance of database context
        private readonly ClinicalDbContext _db;
        #endregion
        #region Public constructor 

        public Repo_Account(ClinicalDbContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }
        #endregion
        //AddNewAccount ChangePassword ChangeEmailAddress Verify_Login
        #region Add new account
        public void AddNewAccount(Account account)
        {
            _db.Accounts.Add(account);
            _db.SaveChanges();
        }
        #endregion
```

And Finally the cshtml page

```
    [![<input id="email" asp-for="Model.UserName" >
                                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                        <span asp-validation-for="Model.UserName" class="alert-danger"></span>
                                    </div>
 <input asp-for="Model.Password" class="form-control" >
                                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                    <span asp-validation-for="Model.Password" class="alert-danger"></span>
                                </div>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" >
                                    Login
                                </button>][2]][2]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't defined a property named `Model` in your Login page. You have defined one called `Account` instead. Change the code as follows:

```
[![<input id="email" asp-for="Account.UserName" >
 <div class="invalid-feedback">
     <span asp-validation-for="Account.UserName" class="alert-danger"></span>
 </div>
 <input asp-for="Account.Password" class="form-control" >
 <div class="invalid-feedback">
     <span asp-validation-for="Account.Password" class="alert-danger"></span>
 </div>

 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" >Login</button>][2]][2]
```

Comment: Thank You sir , I still new with razor pages , i have used to build aspx pages . 
I have seen the dotnetting page of you ..... and wow ,  fabulous page indeed !. 
Blesses and thank you again :)